# setTimeout not working, other methods of queuing in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Code below (the divs are shaded in my real example, I want to sequentially decrease their opacity to 0 so each disappears, in order.

I tried to doing this without using setTimeout, but all of the divs disappeared simultaneously - its good to know that the part of the code that changes the opacity works, but I cant seem to get them to work sequentially.

When I try to use setTimeout (which I presume I am implementing incorrectly),nothing happens!

Any help would be really appreciated with this, I'm fairly new to JavaScript and haven't touched it in a while and tutorials haven't been able to help me.

```
<body>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div id="div4"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    // the divs that we want to cycle through are named here.
    var divs = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3", "#div4"];
    var divsLength = divs.length;   

        for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
              $(divs[i]).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {   
              });
            },1500);
        };  

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, the final argument (1500) is the number of milliseconds before the scripts kicks off. That's why they are all disappearing simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you should be able to do this without `setTimeout`:

```
function doFade(items, index) {
    $(items[index]).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
        doFade(items, index + 1);
    });
}

doFade(divs, 0);
```

If you're targetting browsers that support ES5 (most modern versions do), then you can further simplify doFade:

```
function doFade(items, index) {
    $(items[index]).fadeTo(1000, 0, doFade.bind(this, items, index + 1));
}
```

[working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdxf4u8h/2/)

Comment: Nice clean and simple.

Comment: Thank you, this has really helped to explain this to me in a simple way and works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive function to do that kind of thing, something like that :

```
function seqFade($el){
    $el.first().fadeOut(500, function(){ //Take the first element and fade it out
        seqFade($el.slice(1)); //Recall the function when complete with the same set of element minus the first one.
    })
}

seqFade($('div')); //Call the function
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L2fvdfy2/

In your code, it could look like that :

```
function seqFade($el){
    $el.first().fadeOut(500, function(){
        seqFade($el.slice(1));
    })
}

seqFade($('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4'));
```

Comment: $el.first() reduces $el to only the first element (see jQuery docs), so after the first turn div2, 3 and 4 are gone!

Comment: @MartinErnst `$el.first()` does not modify `$el`. The example above works. You can try it in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Karl-Andre´Gagnon, @JLRishe: both you are right - and I have learned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because when the timeout finally fires the variable "i" only has the last index value. Also the loop will start all the timeouts at almost the same time.

There are other ways to accomplish it but this might work with minimal changes to your code.

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var divs = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3", "#div4"];
    var divsLength = divs.length;   

        for (var i = 0; i < divsLength; i++) {
            setTimeout((function(index) { 
              return function(){ 
                $(divs[index]).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() { });
              }
            )(i)),1500 + (i * 1500));
        };  

    </script>
</body>
```

This will create an instance of the function with it's own copy of the index when it was called. Also increasing the timeout of each timeout will have them execute sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
// the divs that we want to cycle through are named here.
var divs = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3", "#div4"];

(function fade(i) {
    $(divs[i]).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {fade(++i);}, 500);
    });
})(0);
```

Comment: Why `++i` instead of `i + 1`?

Comment: Yes, I know they will both work, but I was asking _why_ you would use `++i` here. It's a good idea not to have side effects in your code when they serve no purpose.

Comment: I think they have no differences. I'd like to ask you why i+1 instead of ++i?

Comment: Like I already said, because it's good to avoid code with side effects unless you need them. `i + 1` leaves the value of `i` unchanged. `++i` changes the value of `i` for no good reason here (and as an added drawback, will consume extra CPU cycles).

Comment: There isn't any reason or purpose for changing value of i. It isn't any matter in this code. It's kind of coding style. :) And I'm not sure, but I don't think the same operation of adding make any extra CPU cycles.

Comment: I know it doesn't make a difference here, but that's all the more reason _not_ to use `++i` when there's no good reason for it. One should get in the habit of avoiding unnecessary side-effects. As for CPU cycles, `++i` has to (1) calculate the value of i + 1 (2) change the value of `i` (3) return the value calculated in step (1). `i + 1` doesn't need to do step 2, so it could easily use fewer CPU cycles. It's not like there would ever be a noticeable speed difference, but again, no need to use extra CPU cycles for no good reason.

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (var i = 1; i <= divsLength; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(){ 
          $(divs[i]).fadeTo(1000, 0, function() {   
          });
        },1000*i);
```

lets try this

Comment: Why? Explain what you've changed, why you think it was wrong, he isn't going to improve his code if you just say "here do this" (I can see the changes, but make it obvious for the OP)